# How are relationships saved in the popular Ember.js adapters?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I think data relationships are saved in the adapters of the Ember app. So the way the REST adapter, the local storage adapter, and the fixture adapter saves relationships might be all different.  Relationships might be saved in the parent or the child.

I would like to know how each adapter saves relationships. Source code and examples would be appreciated.  I'll update with my findings as well.