# Can I set up a many-to-many relationship on just one side in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the [Ember tutorial](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_many-to-many), the many-to-many relationship is introduced as:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post')
});
```

Is it possible to just put 1 of these `DS.hasMany` relationships. For example (let me know if my code is incorrect in any way):

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  postid: DS.attr('number'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  tagid: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

So that can have a JSON like in these fixture adapter setup:

```
App.Tag.FIXTURES = [{
    tagid: 1111,
    name: 'Ember.js',
}, {
    tagid: 2222,
    name: 'Javascript'
}];

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    postid: 3000,
    content: 'A JS Question'
    tags: [2222]
}, {
    postid: 4000,
    content: 'An Ember.js Question',
    tags: [1111, 2222]
}];
```

So basically the many-to-many relationship is just established in the parent, that's why I didn't include `posts: DS.hsaMany('App.Post')` in the `App.Tag` model.

Is what I'm doing okay? If so, when should I need `DS.hasMany` in both models?
If not, please correct the Fixture JSON as well.

If the type of adapter makes a difference, please also explain how they're different (related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688671/how-are-relationships-saved-in-the-popular-ember-js-adapters)).

---

Update: Since intuitivepixel clarified with me that relationship must be many-to-many, let me try it again:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  postid: DS.attr('number'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  tagid: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post')
});
```

Can the Fixture adapter setup be like this, where the relationship is ONLY defined in the posts?

```
App.Tag.FIXTURES = [{
    tagid: 1111,
    name: 'Ember.js',
}, {
    tagid: 2222,
    name: 'Javascript'
}];

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    postid: 3000,
    content: 'A JS Question'
    tags: [2222]
}, {
    postid: 4000,
    content: 'An Ember.js Question',
    tags: [1111, 2222]
}];
```

Or does it have to be like this, where the relationship is defined in both.  If so, wouldn't the information be redundant?  Redundancy is terrible though. :(

```
App.Tag.FIXTURES = [{
    tagid: 1111,
    name: 'Ember.js',
    posts: [4000]
}, {
    tagid: 2222,
    name: 'Javascript',
    posts: [3000, 4000]
}];

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    postid: 3000,
    content: 'A JS Question'
    tags: [2222]
}, {
    postid: 4000,
    content: 'An Ember.js Question',
    tags: [1111, 2222]
}];
```

Comment: your second fixtures are the correct ones. as for the redundancy, this is the nature of a many-to-many relationship

Comment: I've included a small jsbin that show how many-to-many could work, have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: I have the very same issue. You can either have the redundant information, write a serializer or extend the fixture adapter. I've chosen to write a serializer to take care of the redundancy for me. That might be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to just put 1 of these DS.hasMany relationships.

Yes, but this would be then a one-to-many relationship.

> So basically the many-to-many relationship is just established in the parent, that's why I didn't include posts: DS.hasMany('App.Post') in the App.Tag model.

What you are trying to do doesn't work, you need then a one-to-many relationship and your models should look like:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  postid: DS.attr('number'),
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  tagid: DS.attr('number'),
  name: DS.attr('string')
  post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

And the correspondent FIXTURES then:

```
App.Tag.FIXTURES = [{
  tagid: 1111,
  name: 'Ember.js',
  post: 4000
}, {
  tagid: 2222,
  name: 'Javascript',
  post: 4000
}];

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
  postid: 4000,
  content: 'An Ember.js Question',
  tags: [1111, 2222]
}];
```

> Is what I'm doing okay? If so, when should I need DS.hasMany in both models?

It's not really ok, IMHO (and because of the nature of a `tag`) it should be possible to assign a `tag` to many posts, and many tags could be assigned to a `post`. So we end up using a many-to-many relationship like in the ember tutorial you mentioned, there is a reason for that I guess.

So the final answer to your question: *can i set up a many-to-many relationship on just-one side in ember-js* would be - No!

**Update**

I've put togheter a small example how a many-to-many relationship would work, [see here](http://jsbin.com/oyuvog/4/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The fixtures of your answer doesn't reflect the fact tagid 2222 is also in postid 3000.  So a post can have multiple tags and a tag can be in multiple posts, which **does** make them qualify as a many-to-many relationship, right?

Comment: @HaoQiLi my answer show the way of doing a one-to-many relationship only, but a many-to-many would be the correct way

Comment: Question updated. @intuitivepixel, I would like to give you a 50 bounty for helping me all the time, so I won't accept your answer yet.

Comment: @HaoQiLi, you got an upvote, so you have some points to spend :)

Comment: how come [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obowar/1/edit) is working without defining the relationship in "Tag"s at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the RESTAdapter. That way, you are loading the tags alongside with the posts. But as intuitivepixel correctly points out, this is not a truly many-to-many relationship.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Post.find();
  }
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.Adapter.map('App.Post', {
  tags: { embedded: 'load' }
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: App.Adapter.create({
    namespace: 'api'
  })
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  content: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('App.Tag')
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And your JSON payload would be:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 4000,
      "content": "An Ember.js Question",
      "tags": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "ember.js"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "javascript"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "ember-data"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```